# $\sup$ of a $C^s$ smooth function.

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove that for a function $F\in C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which vanishes at zero, and a function $u\in H^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$we get:

$$\left\| \int_{r=0}^1 F'(ru)(\cdot)dr \right\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq \sup_{|v| \leq c\|u\|_{H^k}} |F'(v)(\cdot)|$$
where $c$ is some constant.
So far I got the following:

$$\left\| \int_{r=0}^1F'(ru)(\cdot)dr \right\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\sup_{r\in [0,1]} |F'(ru)(x)|$$

I don't see how to arrive at this bound: $\sup_{|v|\leq c\|u\|_{H^k}}|F'(v)(\cdot)|$.

Any advice or hints are welcomed.
PS
$k$ is an integer.

Comment: Again assume $s$ is an integer? If yes, please use $k$ or $m$ instead of $s$ since $s$ usually denote a real number especially when we talk about Sobolev space defined via Fourier transformation.

Comment: I changed it to $k$, but does someone know how to show this inequality?

Comment: I think you may have $F\in C^k(\mathbb R)$ but not $C^k(\mathbb R^N)$ since you have $u\in H^k(\mathbb R^N;\mathbb R)$. Please revise your question